# AlertDialogs and widgets

Tags: android

I am about to start developing a widget and want to know if on the click of a widget an AlertDialog can created?

Anyways many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't create alert dialogs in homescreen widgets

Comment: So is there anyway i can make something that looks like one?

Comment: maybe you can do something with relative layout and playing with the views visibility, but i'm not sure about that.